# Undefined type in block design when using custom IP

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am busy getting some hands on experience using Xilinx Vivado.

Taking a VHDL sine generator from github (https://github.com/jorisvr/vhdl_sincos_gen) I made an IP package out of it. I defined the ports:
[image]

So the 'in_phase' port is of type unsigned.

After packaging the IP I created a new project with a block design and instantiated the IP:

[image]

This works and I can synthesize the design. Simulation however fails. I get the following errors in the elaboration log:

```
Starting static elaboration
ERROR: [VRFC 10-619] entity port in_phase does not match with type std_logic_vector of component port [/home/dinne/Xilinx/projects/nexys4ddr_tst/nexys4ddr_tst.ip_user_files/bd/design_1/ip/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0/sim/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0.vhd:80]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-619] entity port out_sin does not match with type std_logic_vector of component port [/home/dinne/Xilinx/projects/nexys4ddr_tst/nexys4ddr_tst.ip_user_files/bd/design_1/ip/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0/sim/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0.vhd:81]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-619] entity port out_cos does not match with type std_logic_vector of component port [/home/dinne/Xilinx/projects/nexys4ddr_tst/nexys4ddr_tst.ip_user_files/bd/design_1/ip/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0/sim/design_1_sincos_gen_0_0.vhd:82]
```

Somehow the port types are changed. If I check the port properties of for example the "in_phase" port I see that the type is "undef".
[image]

Also If I check the generated IP wrapper code I see that the port types have changed. Again the 'in_phase' port should be unsigned, but is "std_logic_vector".

[image]

How to fix the IP port types and get the simulation to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vivado only allows ports of types `std_logic` or `std_logic_vector` for custom IPs. Details can be found [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_2/ug1118-vivado-creating-packaging-custom-ip.pdf). Under the section **Top-Level HDL Requirements**, on Page 12 in this document they clearly mention:

> Regardless of the top-level port type, when you synthesize the IP out-of-context (OOC), the resulting IP netlist ports are converted to std_logic or std_logic_vector. **The converted netlist ports could cause type mismatch issues with RTL simulation.** For Verilog, module declarations with complex or split ports are not supported.

And in the same document, on page 63, under the section **Ports and Interfaces**:

> **° Type Name:** The port type (std_logic or std_logic_vector).

As each custom-IP is considered as a top level entity, using `unsigned` type in the top port is unfortunately not supported.